# Unable to access a folder through group permissions

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, chmod, chown

In order to secure data on my webserver, I have moved the PHP includes to a folder called /var/www-includes (outside of /var/www, the server root). I also ran `chown root:wwwadmin` and `chmod 770` on that folder. When I run `ls -ld` on the folder, it verifies the settings: `drwxrwx--- ... root wwwadmin ... www-includes` Although I am able to cd to the folder from my main user (adam) who is a member of wwwadmin,  I cannot view its contents in a graphical file browser. Any idea why?
Edit: Also, when trying to edit the contained files in nano, it shows me an error message:
`Error reading /home/adam/.nano_history: Permission denied`
then opens the contents of the file. Is this relevant at all to what may be going on?

Comment: If you recently added `adam` to the `wwwadmin` group, you should log out of the account, then back in again to be able to access files under the `wwwadmin` group.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps an obvious question but... did you change also the permissions of files inside the directory? In other words, did you use the "-r" (recursive) flag when issuing the chown/chmod commands?

Comment: It's not necessarily relevant to my question... I couldn't change current directory to that folder because of its execute permissions - nothing to do with the files.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not an answer (as the post doesn't include enough information) but I can amend it if needed. When doing linux training courses I developed a way to quickly find the permission problem. I'm aware that you already performed some of the steps but I need to write it down in full for the sake of completeness.

1. Switch to the user you want to use for access. Do it before doing anything else.
2. Use `id` command to check your current UID and groups. Use `id name-of-the-user` to check the on-disk configuration. Log out and log back in if they differ and check again.
3. Use 'ls -l' to check the target directory. Don't forget to check the character just after the permissions. There may be a dot meaning ere's a selinux context or there may be a plus sign meaning linux ACLs are set.
4. Use 'cd' to get into the directory.
5. Perform necessary actions on the regular files. Use `touch` to check write access, `cat` to check read access.
6. Check whether everything works as expected on the application level (e.g. use a browser to access the URL that should result in the respective action, use your favourite editing tool that previously failed, etc)
7. Add any of the above checks to the application level.

If any of the action fails and you have no idea why, check the logs for selinux alerts or similar. You can also try to prepend `strace -o strace.log` to the command line and then check the strace.log for *permission denied* messages. But it's all black magic until you know the exact reason for *permission denied*.